# Python Read CSV File By Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am using following python code to read csv file data :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
df = pd.read_csv("D:\Projects\BehaviorMining\breast-cancer.csv")
```

It returns error

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\Projects\BehaviorMining\x08reast-cancer.csv'

I thought csv file has problem ,because some csv files has no problem with above syntax ,
but I didn't find any problem in csv file.

Thanks for any guides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use single quotation marks only or use 'r' raw string upfront and a single '/'. For example

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\Projects\BehaviorMining\breast-cancer.csv')
```

Comment: I think your "and" should be an "or", no? ;)

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. I was typing in a hurry

Comment: (not fully sure of my edit I'm not using windows, feel free to remove)

Comment: I don't use windows either. Probably someone who does, can make sure it's right xD

Comment: Then better leave it out, your initial solution should work for sure

Comment: Okay, sounds fine to me